# Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm using titanium studio 3.4 and every time I want to run my application on android emulator `genemotion` API 18

I get this error after

```
[INFO] :   Making sure the adb server is running

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn OK
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
```

Comment: Maybe this may help you: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140526/solution-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination

Comment: have u solved your issue?

Answer (score -1):

Use Android SDK tools instead of in-built Genymotions SDk
I solved my problem with this